# Access to bing maps via Excel 2013 with PowerView blocked by fw

Tags: bing-maps, excel-2013, akamai, powerview

Here is my problem.

I have a client that uses the plug-in powerview through Excel2013 .

At the beginning my client hadn't at all access as our firewall was blocking the access to the office365 IP and Bing.com.

Once the flow authorized on the firewall, he don't have any error message but nothing happens.

When he try to access bing.com/maps the map cannot be displayed at the same moment I did verify my firewall and I see that his machine tries to access an AKAMAI IP(same thing when he goes through powerview) . Every time that he tries to access bing maps we have a random AKAMAI ip adress and so it is blocked by the firewall.

The idea is to authorize only the flow towards bing maps and not to ANY destination.

So my question is, is there any way to learn what URL uses powerview so to authorize them on my firewall? Do you ever had such problem?

PS The only solution that I can imagine for the moment, but it is impossible for our Datacenter provider, is to implement a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps has a long list of IP address ranges which need to be allowed through the firewall. Contact the support team using the online form under the developer support section here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx They will be able to provide you with the list you need.

Comment: Hello rbrundritt,
I've sent an email to the maps developers.
I'm waiting for their reply.
Thanks for the suggestion.